# Mercado Pago .Net C#

Tags: c#, api, .net, mercadopago

estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicacion para leer codigo QR y pagar con Mercado Pago, queria saber si alguien sabe como en .net puedo enviar una peticion post con Headers ya que no puedo ... Ahi les pongo mi codigo:

```
    string Url = $"https://api.mercadopago.com/mpmobile/instore/qr/USER_ID/CAJA_ID";
    var Client = new HttpClient();
    CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout oTransaccion = new CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout()
    {
        sku_number = "12345",
        category = "Categoria1",
        title = "TiruloPrueba",
        description = "DescripcionPrueba",
        unit_price = 22,
        quantity = 1,
        unit_measure = "No se que es",
        total_amount = 22            
    };

    var Data = JsonSerializer.Serialize<CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout>(oTransaccion);
    HttpContent contenido = new StringContent(Data, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
    contenido.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer MI_ACCESS_TOKEN");
    contenido.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var httpResponse = await Client.PostAsync(Url, contenido);

    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var Resultado =await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

Y el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
: 'Misused header name, 'Authorization'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'
```

Comment: dice que Authorization se esta enviando en el header y que este no es parte de los header de HttpRequestMessage; no deberías enviarlo como dato ???

Comment: Esa parte lo pude solucionar, tengo que enviarlo en el Client y no en contenido, ahora me encuentro con el siguiente error: No puedo enviar el Content-Type : application/json en el Client

Comment: mmm entonces eso es otra pregunta... otro POST y trata de darle respuesta a este  ....  explica como lo solucionaste ... para que vayas ganando reputación ...